# What's the meaning of "be blowed"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know what's the meaning of "be blowed" in the following text:

> 'I'm going to smoke' Jenkins said; '***be blowed*** to Bertie dear.' (Mrs. Smythe had once addressed her husband in the office as 'Bertie dear', and thereforth that had been his name among the staff.) Richard made no answer. When a minute later Jenkins, discreetly directing his puffs to the open window, asked him for the titles of one or two of Zola's novels in English, and their price, he gave the required information without turning round and in a preoccupied tone.

*[A Man From North](https://archive.org/details/amanfromnorth01benngoog)*, Arnold Bennett, 1911.

Comment: Never heard that one, but it seems from the context that it means, basically, “I’m going to smoke, and Bertie dear can bugger off” or “I’m going to smoke whether Bertie dear likes it or not".

Comment: From the context, it is clear to me that the general sentiment is "I know Bertie said not to, but I am doing it anyway because I choose to disrespect him."  In that sense it is similar to "screw him" or "he can go **** himself".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufWdpNSs3DM  From Wikipedia: "The lyric "Blow the man down" may refer to the act of knocking a man to the ground."

Comment: Arnold Bennett was definitely British. (Sorry, this was meant as a comment on Laurel's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Looking this definition for [**blow**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blow) in Oxford Dictionaries, it likely means *damn*:

> (past participle blowed) [ with obj., usu. as imperative ] Brit. informal **damn**: "Well, blow me," he said, "I never knew that" | [ with clause ] : I'm blowed if I want to see him again.

Although the book was published in New York, it's obvious that it uses British English, as it's dedicated "to the one whom I most hono**u**r".

Answer (score 1):

I think is  a usage derived from the old-fashioned expression  ***[be blowed if](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-blowed-if)***...suggesting that you are determined to to  something against the will of someone else or not caring what others may think about it.

​

> - If someone says that they are blowed if they will do something, they are determined not to do it:
>
>   - *I'm blowed if I'm going to pay for his taxi home*.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Blowed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blowed)*** is the nonstandard:

> - simple past tense and past participle of blow.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

***Blow*** is used as an imprecation (often because it is less offensive than what would be considered swearing). Sense 29 from the OED provides some interesting examples:

> 29. Used in imprecations: To curse, ‘confound’, ‘hang’. vulgar. (The pa. pple. is blowed.) Also with the implication of ignoring or
>       disregarding; blow!: used absol. as an exclamation of anger or
>       vexation; blow me tight! (cf. sense  22).
>
> 1781   G. Parker View Society & Manners I. 48   Blow me up (says he)
>   if I have had a fellow with such rum toggys cross my company these
>   many a day.
>
> 1819   T. Moore Tom Crib's Memorial to Congress 46   Says Bill,
>   ‘there's nothing like a Bull: And blow me tight.’
>
> 1821   P. Egan Life in London iii. 225   Blow me tight if ever I saw
>   such a thing in my life before.
>
> 1827   J. Wight More Mornings at Bow St. 55   Blow me if I do!
>
> 1836   Dickens Sketches by Boz 2nd Ser. 184   The said Thomas
>   Sludberry repeated the aforesaid expression, ‘You be blowed’.
>
> 1840   F. Marryat Olla Podrida III. 20   If I do, blow me!
>
> 1859   Dickens Tale of Two Cities ii. i. 36   One blowed thing and
>   another.
>
> 1865   Dickens Our Mutual Friend II. iv. xv. 287   Blowed if I
>   shouldn't have left out lakes.
>
> 1871   Blackwood's Edinb. Mag. May 551/2   Oh, blow it, governor.
>
> 1881   Daily Tel. 28 Jan.   ‘Isn't it rather risky?’ I asked. ‘Blow
>   risks,’ he answered.
>
> 1882   J. A. Lees & W. J. Clutterbuck Three in Norway xxiv. 207
>   Retributive justice be blowed!
>
> 1922   F. Hamilton P. J.: Secret Service Boy ii. 70   I'm absolutely
>   blowed if I know what to do.
>
> 1922   F. Hamilton P. J.: Secret Service Boy ii. 84   Oh, blow! And I
>   go back to school in ten days.
>
> 1933   P. MacDonald Myst. Dead Police i. 6   ‘Blow me tight!’ said
>   Sergeant Guilfoil. For things were certainly happening in Farnley.
>
> 1957   I. Cross God Boy (1958) xv. 124   Then blow me if Dr
>   Hutchinson..didn't come padding round the post office corner.
>
> 1963   Listener 28 Mar. 540/1   It is no longer proper to use as our
>   second national motto in education ‘Blow you, Jack, our top five per
>   cent. are absolutely splendid’.

Answer (score -1):

As per JOSH's answer, the root phrase is something like [Blow me down](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-blow-me-down-mean.htm#comments), or [I'll be blown](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-blo6.htm). The origin of the phrase and usage of 'blow' seems to be the nautical term for gale and can also survives in shanties such as 'Blow the man down' where it may refer to a '[knockdown](http://www.schoolofsailing.net/glossary.html)' when a ship under sail is hit by a sharp gust which fills the sails and heels it over on its beam ends. It seems likely that 'blow me tight' references the same phenomenon.

> "Blow me tight if ’ere ain’t a gentleman been looking for Wallingford
>   lock, Bill!”
>  *Three men in a Boat Jerome K Jerome 1888*

Comment: Largely yes and please note that 'I'll be blown' has no place here.

'I'll be blowed' is what you meant.

If it has an idiomatic meaning, 'I'll be blown' refers to oral sex…