# The meaning of 'blow me down'

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of this sentence below from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English?

> ▪ Blow me down if she didn’t just run off!

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blow-blow-me-blow-it-etc

The Longman Dictionary says you use 'blow me' to show annoyance or surprise and is usually used in British English.
But I still cannot figure out what it means and in what situation it can be used.

Comment: A related question has been asked before. https://english.stackexchange.com/q/363308/168678

Comment: Reminds me of _Popeye the Sailor Man_. Good old days. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Blow+me+down+popeye

Comment: Reading thru other examples from OLD would give a clearer picture: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/blow_me_down

Comment: Are you asking about "blow me" or "blow me down"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a term like many others whose usage has metamorphosed. Begin with "When she just ran off, you could have knocked me over with a feather!" It suggests that sudden shock and surprise renders a person weak and liable to faint. Now "She's run off ? - well blow me down!". Modify that slightly "Blow me down if she just didn't just run off". It is idiomatic.

For a wider treatment on the use of ***blow*** as an imprecation etc see the answer I have provided with OED reference at: [english.stackexchange.com/q/363308/168678](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363308/whats-the-meaning-of-be-blowed)

Answer (score -3):

"Blow me" as a two-word message has a very specific and rude meaning to native speakers. It's a vulgar slang phrase that means "Give me a blow-job" (oral sex), and it's usually said in the spirit of "fuck you", rather than a literal request.

Eg:
"I don't think what you just said to that man is acceptable."
"Blow me."

Comment: I disagree with that. Yes, the words can mean to give someone a blow job in a different context; but when used to express surprise it's not that meaning, but the "you could blow me down with a feather" sense.